# MediaWiki API with PHP

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

Okay I wish to make a simple program that fetches the latest edits from a MediaWiki site (namely Wikias Community Central) and displays them neatly in a table. I know how to get all the display and sorting stuff code made but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the info from the server. I know in javascript I can create an ajax request to an api.php document which contains several url variables. Is there a similar way to do this in PHP as well?

Comment: php-curl, file_get_contents, and many many others...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$response = json_decode(file_get_contents($url))`

Comment: My issue is that I don't really know how to set up an Ajax request with PHP.

Comment: Although this will be helpful once I figure that out.

Comment: I feel stupid now... I know what to do! Thank you so much.